# Dividir array map erroneo

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, frontend

estoy obteniendo de una llamada un array bidimensional, pero necesito trabajar con el dato. Para eso estoy haciendo un map y luego sobre el otro map, pero en vez de darme un array por cada valor me da un array con los valores y otro vacio. Queria tener un array por valor, gracias!!

```
   const development = products.map((x) => {
     
         return x.sustainabilityGoalDtoList.map((y) => {
           return y.desc
    
         })  
})
```

El resultado que me da es esto

```
0: Array [ "Fin de la pobreza", "Hambre cero" ]
​
1: Array []
​
length: 2,
```

pero yo necesitaria esto:

```
  0: Array [ "Fin de la pobreza" ]
    ​
    1: Array [ "Hambre cero"]
    ​
    length: 2,
```

El objeto  products es asi:

```
regionId: 1
​​
size: 5

​​
stateId: 36
​​
stockCredits: 455
​​
sustainabilityGoalDtoList: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​​​
0: Object { id: 1, color: "#e5233d", position: 1, … }
​​​​
color: "#e5233d"
​​​​
desc: "Fin de la pobreza"
​​​​
id: 1
​​​​
name: "Fin de la pobreza"
​​​​
position: 1
​​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​​
1: Object { id: 2, color: "#d3a029", position: 2, … }
​​​​
color: "#d3a029"
​​​​
desc: "Hambre cero"
​​​​
id: 2
​​​​
name: "Hambre cero"
​​​​
position: 2
​​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​​
length: 2
​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​

​​
updatedDate: "2022-11-18"
```

**necesitaria sacar la parte sustainabilityGoalDtoLis en dos arrays, uno por lista**

Comment: Pon parte del objeto inicial, por favor, para que podamos reproducir el error y jugar con ello.

Comment: lo acabo de poner arriba

Comment: Como comprenderás, con ese objeto tal como lo has puesto no nos ayudas a ayudarte, pues tenemos que rehacerlo en formato javascript para reproducir tu error. Si tienes un json ponlo, si tienes un objeto con la sintaxis correcta de objeto ponlo, pero no pongas eso porque nos dificultas reproducir el error pues supone un tiempo enorme pasarlo a código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de esta forma, retornando un array por cada iteración, al final como resultado obtendrás un array con otros arrays dentro.

```
const development = products.map((x) => {
    return x.sustainabilityGoalDtoList.map((y) => {
        return new Array(y.desc)
    })
})

console.log(development)
```

Ya teniendo el array `development` podrás hacer con él lo que quieras utilizando los métodos correspondientes para un array.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]